# Dynamically populate query source in Elementor post widget

Tags: custom-field, query

I want to call dyanamically categories in the post widget of Elementor. I created a function to call results from a field created with ACF (a dropbox select of posts categories):

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/acf_filter', function( $query ) {
    $value = the_field( "category_filters" );
}, 10, 1);
```

That query doesn't work. All the categories are rendered instead of selected ones. Above, there is the field rendered with categories ID, see the photo:  [image: the]

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is it:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/acf_filter', function( $query ) {
    $filtre = get_field( "category_filters" );
    $query-> set('cat' , $filtre );

} );
```